# Damping bridge question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> When first opened, the Millennium Bridge in London wobbled from side
>    to side as people crossed; you can see this on video at
>    www.arup.com/MillenniumBridge. Footfalls created small side-to-side
>    movements of the bridge, which were then enhanced by the tendency of
>    people to adjust their steps to compensate for wobbling. With more
>    than a critical number of pedestrians (around 160) the bridge began to
>    wobble violently. Without any pedestrians, the displacement x of a
>    representative point on the bridge away from its normal position would
>    satisfy $Mx'' + kx' + λx = 0$, where $M ≈ 4 × 10^5kg$, $k ≈ 5 ×  10^4kg/s$, $λ ≈ 10^7kg/s$
>
> Show that the level of damping here is only
>   around 1% of the critical value

I did $k^2-4Mλ$ which is a large value nowhere close to 0. In the answer they work out the value of $k$ from $M$ and $λ$,  knowing that $k^2-4Mλ=0$ and they show that they given value of k is around 1% to the worked out value of k. I dont understand how working out this answers the question as k is not the damping itself

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any damping, the bridge would oscillate with a frequency proportional to $\sqrt{\lambda/M}$. Note that the unit of $\lambda$ is $kg/s^2$ not $kg/s$. People don't like to walk on oscillating bridges, so the architect/constructor make sure that the oscillations are damped. Preferably, the damping factor should be at least equal to the critical damping. You calculate the critical damping by $k_c^2-4M\lambda=0$. The actual damping of the bridge in question was far less than the desired value. Additional dampers were added to the bridge later. See [here](http://www.taylordevices.com/papers/damper/damper.pdf), page 8.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to say, I dont see what's achieved with calculating the value of k given there should be critical damping and why the ratio of the given k to this worked out k matters. Because what i have done is i have calculated the 'actual damping' and the critical damping but the proportion is nowhere near 1%. Is this purely because of the incorrect lambda which you mentioned or is this just the wrong way to go about it @Andrei

Comment: I get $k_c=4\times10^6 kg/s$, which is almost 100 times greater than the given $k$. To be exact $k/k_c\cdot 100=1.25$. I've multiplied with 100, to get the value as a percentage